# Expand and collapse item in recyclerview when the user holding item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a problem.

I am trying to create an element in the recycle view, which, when you click and hold an item, expands the element and displays some of the data.

I do this using onLongClickListener, but when the user stops touching the button, the element is further expanded

What do I have to do to collapse an item when the user stops holding the item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onTouchEvent` does what you want:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

int eventAction = event.getAction();

// you may need the x/y location
int x = (int)event.getX();
int y = (int)event.getY();

// put your code in here to handle the event
switch (eventAction) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        break;
}

// tell the View to redraw the Canvas
invalidate();

// tell the View that we handled the event
return true;
```

}

If you want to read more you can check [this](https://alvinalexander.com/android/android-ontouchevent-example-method-view-class) and [this](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector) link.